# Am I going to lose my UK permanent residence and if so, what is the reapplication process?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, resident-permit

I am London resident and hold UK Permanent residence.

Soon, I will depart for Auckland (I am a NZ Citizen) to live.

Is there a chance I will lose my permanent residency in the UK?

If so, is there a way to re-apply easily?

Answer (score 3):

You will lose your permanent residency after leaving the UK for two years. When you lose your permanent residency, your status and your rights are exactly the same as those of a NZ citizen who never left his country.